# org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user

Tags: tomcat

org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user
i m unable to open tomcat login , can anyone tell me how to clear this log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unlock a tomcat user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308992/how-to-unlock-a-tomcat-user)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.